# Error 1064 on Trigger with Function

Tags: mysql

I am trying to populate a column in `schema_premises.table_premises` with the Double Metaphone equivalents using the following stored function taken from [here](https://github.com/AtomBoy/double-metaphone):

```
-- This SQL implements the Double Metaphone algorythm (c) 1998, 1999 by Lawrence Philips
-- it was translated to Python, and then to SQL from the C source written by Kevin Atkinson (http://aspell.net/metaphone/)
-- By Andrew Collins (atomodo.com) - Feb, 2007 who claims no rights to this work
-- github.com/AtomBoy/double-metaphone
-- Tested with MySQL 5.1 on Ubuntu 6.01 and Ubuntu 10.4
-- Updated Nov 27, 2007 to fix a bug in the 'CC' section
-- Updated Jun 01, 2010 to fix a bug in the 'Z' section - thanks Nils Johnsson!
-- Updated Jun 25, 2010 to fix 16 signifigant bugs - thanks again Nils Johnsson for a spectacular
--   bug squashing effort. There were many cases where this function wouldn't give the same output
--   as the original C source that were fixed by his careful attention and excellent communication.
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `dm` $$

CREATE FUNCTION `dm`(st VARCHAR(55)) RETURNS varchar(128) CHARSET utf8
    NO SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE length, first, last, pos, prevpos, is_slavo_germanic SMALLINT;
    DECLARE pri, sec VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE ch CHAR(1);
    -- returns the double metaphone code OR codes for given string
    -- if there is a secondary dm it is separated with a semicolon
    -- there are no checks done on the input string, but it should be a single word OR name.
    --  st is short for string. I usually prefer descriptive over short, but this var is used a lot!
    SET first = 3;
    SET length = CHAR_LENGTH(st);
    SET last = first + length -1;
    SET st = CONCAT(REPEAT('-', first -1), UCASE(st), REPEAT(' ', 5)); --  pad st so we can index beyond the begining AND end of the input string
    SET is_slavo_germanic = (st LIKE '%W%' OR st LIKE '%K%' OR st LIKE '%CZ%');  -- the check for '%W%' will catch WITZ
    SET pos = first; --  pos is short for position
    -- skip these silent letters when at start of word
    IF SUBSTRING(st, first, 2) IN ('GN', 'KN', 'PN', 'WR', 'PS') THEN
        SET pos = pos + 1;
    END IF;
    --  Initial 'X' is pronounced 'Z' e.g. 'Xavier'
    IF SUBSTRING(st, first, 1) = 'X' THEN
        SET pri = 'S', sec = 'S', pos = pos  + 1; -- 'Z' maps to 'S'
    END IF;
    --  main loop through chars IN st
    WHILE pos <= last DO
        -- print str(pos) + '\t' + SUBSTRING(st, pos)
    SET prevpos = pos;
        SET ch = SUBSTRING(st, pos, 1); --  ch is short for character
        CASE
        WHEN ch IN ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y') THEN
            IF pos = first THEN --  all init vowels now map to 'A'
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'A'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'A'), pos = pos  + 1; -- nxt = ('A', 1)
            ELSE
                SET pos = pos + 1;
            END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'B' THEN
            -- '-mb', e.g', 'dumb', already skipped over... see 'M' below
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'B' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'P'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'P'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('P', 2)
            ELSE
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'P'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'P'), pos = pos  + 1; -- nxt = ('P', 1)
            END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'C' THEN
            --  various germanic
            IF (pos > (first + 1) AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-2, 1) NOT IN ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y') AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 3) = 'ACH' AND
               (SUBSTRING(st, pos+2, 1) NOT IN ('I', 'E') OR SUBSTRING(st, pos-2, 6) IN ('BACHER', 'MACHER'))) THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('K', 2)
            --  special case 'CAESAR'
            ELSEIF pos = first AND SUBSTRING(st, first, 6) = 'CAESAR' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'S'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'S'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('S', 2)
            ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 4) = 'CHIA' THEN -- italian 'chianti'
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('K', 2)
            ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 2) = 'CH' THEN
                --  find 'michael'
                IF pos > first AND SUBSTRING(st, pos, 4) = 'CHAE' THEN
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'X'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('K', 'X', 2)
                ELSEIF pos = first AND (SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 5) IN ('HARAC', 'HARIS') OR
                   SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 3) IN ('HOR', 'HYM', 'HIA', 'HEM')) AND SUBSTRING(st, first, 5) != 'CHORE' THEN
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('K', 2)
                -- germanic, greek, OR otherwise 'ch' for 'kh' sound
                ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, first, 4) IN ('VAN ', 'VON ') OR SUBSTRING(st, first, 3) = 'SCH'
                   OR SUBSTRING(st, pos-2, 6) IN ('ORCHES', 'ARCHIT', 'ORCHID')
                   OR SUBSTRING(st, pos+2, 1) IN ('T', 'S')
                   OR ((SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 1) IN ('A', 'O', 'U', 'E') OR pos = first)
                   AND SUBSTRING(st, pos+2, 1) IN ('L', 'R', 'N', 'M', 'B', 'H', 'F', 'V', 'W', ' ')) THEN
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('K', 2)
                ELSE
                    IF pos > first THEN
                        IF SUBSTRING(st, first, 2) = 'MC' THEN
                            SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('K', 2)
                        ELSE
                            SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'X'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('X', 'K', 2)
                        END IF;
                    ELSE
                        SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'X'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'X'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('X', 2)
                    END IF;
                END IF;
            -- e.g, 'czerny'
            ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 2) = 'CZ' AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-2, 4) != 'WICZ' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'S'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'X'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('S', 'X', 2)
            -- e.g., 'focaccia'
            ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 3) = 'CIA' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'X'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'X'), pos = pos  + 3; -- nxt = ('X', 3)
            -- double 'C', but not IF e.g. 'McClellan'
            ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 2) = 'CC' AND NOT (pos = (first +1) AND SUBSTRING(st, first, 1) = 'M') THEN
                -- 'bellocchio' but not 'bacchus'
                IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+2, 1) IN ('I', 'E', 'H') AND SUBSTRING(st, pos+2, 2) != 'HU' THEN
                    -- 'accident', 'accede' 'succeed'
                    IF (pos = first +1 AND SUBSTRING(st, first) = 'A') OR
                       SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 5) IN ('UCCEE', 'UCCES') THEN
                        SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'KS'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'KS'), pos = pos  + 3; -- nxt = ('KS', 3)
                    -- 'bacci', 'bertucci', other italian
                    ELSE
                        SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'X'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'X'), pos = pos  + 3; -- nxt = ('X', 3)
                    END IF;
                ELSE
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('K', 2)
                END IF;
            ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 2) IN ('CK', 'CG', 'CQ') THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('K', 'K', 2)
            ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 2) IN ('CI', 'CE', 'CY') THEN
                -- italian vs. english
                IF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 3) IN ('CIO', 'CIE', 'CIA') THEN
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'S'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'X'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('S', 'X', 2)
                ELSE
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'S'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'S'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('S', 2)
                END IF;
            ELSE
                -- name sent IN 'mac caffrey', 'mac gregor
                IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 2) IN (' C', ' Q', ' G') THEN
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 3; -- nxt = ('K', 3)
                ELSE
                    IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) IN ('C', 'K', 'Q') AND SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 2) NOT IN ('CE', 'CI') THEN
                        SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('K', 2)
                    ELSE --  default for 'C'
                        SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 1; -- nxt = ('K', 1)
                    END IF;
                END IF;
            END IF;
        -- ELSEIF ch = 'Ç' THEN --  will never get here with st.encode('ascii', 'replace') above
            -- SET pri = CONCAT(pri, '5'), sec = CONCAT(sec, '5'), pos = pos  + 1; -- nxt = ('S', 1)
        WHEN ch = 'D' THEN
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 2) = 'DG' THEN
                IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+2, 1) IN ('I', 'E', 'Y') THEN -- e.g. 'edge'
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'J'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'J'), pos = pos  + 3; -- nxt = ('J', 3)
                ELSE
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'TK'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'TK'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('TK', 2)
                END IF;
            ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 2) IN ('DT', 'DD') THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'T'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'T'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('T', 2)
            ELSE
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'T'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'T'), pos = pos  + 1; -- nxt = ('T', 1)
            END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'F' THEN
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'F' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'F'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'F'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('F', 2)
            ELSE
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'F'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'F'), pos = pos  + 1; -- nxt = ('F', 1)
            END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'G' THEN
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'H' THEN
                IF (pos > first AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 1) NOT IN ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y'))
                    OR ( pos = first AND SUBSTRING(st, pos+2, 1) != 'I') THEN
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('K', 2)
                ELSEIF pos = first AND SUBSTRING(st, pos+2, 1) = 'I' THEN
                     SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'J'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'J'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('J', 2)
                -- Parker's rule (with some further refinements) - e.g., 'hugh'
                ELSEIF (pos > (first + 1) AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-2, 1) IN ('B', 'H', 'D') )
                   OR (pos > (first + 2) AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-3, 1) IN ('B', 'H', 'D') )
                   OR (pos > (first + 3) AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-4, 1) IN ('B', 'H') ) THEN
                    SET pos = pos + 2; -- nxt = (None, 2)
                ELSE
                    --  e.g., 'laugh', 'McLaughlin', 'cough', 'gough', 'rough', 'tough'
                    IF pos > (first + 2) AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 1) = 'U'
                       AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-3, 1) IN ('C', 'G', 'L', 'R', 'T') THEN
                        SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'F'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'F'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('F', 2)
                    ELSEIF pos > first AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 1) != 'I' THEN
                        SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('K', 2)
          ELSE
              SET pos = pos + 1;
                    END IF;
                END IF;
            ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'N' THEN
                IF pos = (first +1) AND SUBSTRING(st, first, 1) IN ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y') AND NOT is_slavo_germanic THEN
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'KN'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'N'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('KN', 'N', 2)
                ELSE
                    --  not e.g. 'cagney'
                    IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+2, 2) != 'EY' AND SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) != 'Y'
                        AND NOT is_slavo_germanic THEN
                        SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'N'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'KN'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('N', 'KN', 2)
                    ELSE
                        SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'KN'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'KN'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('KN', 2)
                    END IF;
                END IF;
            --  'tagliaro'
            ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 2) = 'LI' AND NOT is_slavo_germanic THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'KL'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'L'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('KL', 'L', 2)
            --  -ges-,-gep-,-gel-, -gie- at beginning
            ELSEIF pos = first AND (SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'Y'
               OR SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 2) IN ('ES', 'EP', 'EB', 'EL', 'EY', 'IB', 'IL', 'IN', 'IE', 'EI', 'ER')) THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'J'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('K', 'J', 2)
            --  -ger-,  -gy-
            ELSEIF (SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 2) = 'ER' OR SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'Y')
               AND SUBSTRING(st, first, 6) NOT IN ('DANGER', 'RANGER', 'MANGER')
               AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 1) not IN ('E', 'I') AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 3) NOT IN ('RGY', 'OGY') THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'J'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('K', 'J', 2)
            --  italian e.g, 'biaggi'
            ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) IN ('E', 'I', 'Y') OR SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 4) IN ('AGGI', 'OGGI') THEN
                --  obvious germanic
                IF SUBSTRING(st, first, 4) IN ('VON ', 'VAN ') OR SUBSTRING(st, first, 3) = 'SCH'
                   OR SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 2) = 'ET' THEN
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('K', 2)
                ELSE
                    --  always soft IF french ending
                    IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 4) = 'IER ' THEN
                        SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'J'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'J'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('J', 2)
                    ELSE
                        SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'J'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('J', 'K', 2)
                    END IF;
                END IF;
            ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'G' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('K', 2)
            ELSE
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 1; -- nxt = ('K', 1)
            END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'H' THEN
            --  only keep IF first & before vowel OR btw. 2 ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y')
            IF (pos = first OR SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 1) IN ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y'))
                AND SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) IN ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y') THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'H'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'H'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('H', 2)
            ELSE --  (also takes care of 'HH')
                SET pos = pos + 1; -- nxt = (None, 1)
            END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'J' THEN
            --  obvious spanish, 'jose', 'san jacinto'
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 4) = 'JOSE' OR SUBSTRING(st, first, 4) = 'SAN ' THEN
                IF (pos = first AND SUBSTRING(st, pos+4, 1) = ' ') OR SUBSTRING(st, first, 4) = 'SAN ' THEN
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'H'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'H'); -- nxt = ('H',)
                ELSE
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'J'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'H'); -- nxt = ('J', 'H')
                END IF;
            ELSEIF pos = first AND SUBSTRING(st, pos, 4) != 'JOSE' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'J'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'A'); -- nxt = ('J', 'A') --  Yankelovich/Jankelowicz
            ELSE
                --  spanish pron. of e.g. 'bajador'
                IF SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 1) IN ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y') AND NOT is_slavo_germanic
                   AND SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) IN ('A', 'O') THEN
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'J'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'H'); -- nxt = ('J', 'H')
                ELSE
                    IF pos = last THEN
                        SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'J'); -- nxt = ('J', ' ')
                    ELSE
                        IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) not IN ('L', 'T', 'K', 'S', 'N', 'M', 'B', 'Z')
                           AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 1) not IN ('S', 'K', 'L') THEN
                            SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'J'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'J'); -- nxt = ('J',)
                        END IF;
                    END IF;
                END IF;
            END IF;
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'J' THEN
                SET pos = pos + 2;
            ELSE
                SET pos = pos + 1;
            END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'K' THEN
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'K' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('K', 2)
            ELSE
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 1; -- nxt = ('K', 1)
            END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'L' THEN
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'L' THEN
                --  spanish e.g. 'cabrillo', 'gallegos'
                IF (pos = (last - 2) AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 4) IN ('ILLO', 'ILLA', 'ALLE'))
                   OR ((SUBSTRING(st, last-1, 2) IN ('AS', 'OS') OR SUBSTRING(st, last) IN ('A', 'O'))
                   AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 4) = 'ALLE') THEN
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'L'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('L', ' ', 2)
                ELSE
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'L'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'L'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('L', 2)
                END IF;
            ELSE
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'L'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'L'), pos = pos  + 1; -- nxt = ('L', 1)
            END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'M' THEN
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 3) = 'UMB'
               AND (pos + 1 = last OR SUBSTRING(st, pos+2, 2) = 'ER')
               OR SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'M' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'M'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'M'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('M', 2)
            ELSE
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'M'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'M'), pos = pos  + 1; -- nxt = ('M', 1)
            END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'N' THEN
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'N' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'N'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'N'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('N', 2)
            ELSE
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'N'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'N'), pos = pos  + 1; -- nxt = ('N', 1)
            END IF;
        -- ELSEIF ch = u'Ñ' THEN
            -- SET pri = CONCAT(pri, '5'), sec = CONCAT(sec, '5'), pos = pos  + 1; -- nxt = ('N', 1)
        WHEN ch = 'P' THEN
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'H' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'F'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'F'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('F', 2)
            ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) IN ('P', 'B') THEN --  also account for 'campbell', 'raspberry'
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'P'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'P'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('P', 2)
            ELSE
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'P'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'P'), pos = pos  + 1; -- nxt = ('P', 1)
            END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'Q' THEN
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'Q' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('K', 2)
            ELSE
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 1; -- nxt = ('K', 1)
            END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'R' THEN
            --  french e.g. 'rogier', but exclude 'hochmeier'
            IF pos = last AND not is_slavo_germanic
               AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-2, 2) = 'IE' AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-4, 2) NOT IN ('ME', 'MA') THEN
                SET sec = CONCAT(sec, 'R'); -- nxt = ('', 'R')
            ELSE
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'R'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'R'); -- nxt = ('R',)
            END IF;
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'R' THEN
                SET pos = pos + 2;
            ELSE
                SET pos = pos + 1;
            END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'S' THEN
            --  special cases 'island', 'isle', 'carlisle', 'carlysle'
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 3) IN ('ISL', 'YSL') THEN
                SET pos = pos + 1;
            --  special case 'sugar-'
            ELSEIF pos = first AND SUBSTRING(st, first, 5) = 'SUGAR' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'X'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'S'), pos = pos  + 1; --  nxt =('X', 'S', 1)
            ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 2) = 'SH' THEN
                --  germanic
                IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 4) IN ('HEIM', 'HOEK', 'HOLM', 'HOLZ') THEN
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'S'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'S'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('S', 2)
                ELSE
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'X'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'X'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('X', 2)
                END IF;
            --  italian & armenian
            ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 3) IN ('SIO', 'SIA') OR SUBSTRING(st, pos, 4) = 'SIAN' THEN
                IF NOT is_slavo_germanic THEN
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'S'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'X'), pos = pos  + 3; -- nxt = ('S', 'X', 3)
                ELSE
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'S'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'S'), pos = pos  + 3; -- nxt = ('S', 3)
                END IF;
            --  german & anglicisations, e.g. 'smith' match 'schmidt', 'snider' match 'schneider'
            --  also, -sz- IN slavic language altho IN hungarian it is pronounced 's'
            ELSEIF (pos = first AND SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) IN ('M', 'N', 'L', 'W')) OR SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'Z' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'S'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'X'); -- nxt = ('S', 'X')
                IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'Z' THEN
                    SET pos = pos + 2;
                ELSE
                    SET pos = pos + 1;
                END IF;
            ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 2) = 'SC' THEN
                --  Schlesinger's rule
                IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+2, 1) = 'H' THEN
                    --  dutch origin, e.g. 'school', 'schooner'
                    IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+3, 2) IN ('OO', 'ER', 'EN', 'UY', 'ED', 'EM') THEN
                        --  'schermerhorn', 'schenker'
                        IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+3, 2) IN ('ER', 'EN') THEN
                            SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'X'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'SK'), pos = pos  + 3; -- nxt = ('X', 'SK', 3)
                        ELSE
                            SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'SK'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'SK'), pos = pos  + 3; -- nxt = ('SK', 3)
                        END IF;
                    ELSE
                        IF pos = first AND SUBSTRING(st, first+3, 1) not IN ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y') AND SUBSTRING(st, first+3, 1) != 'W' THEN
                            SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'X'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'S'), pos = pos  + 3; -- nxt = ('X', 'S', 3)
                        ELSE
                            SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'X'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'X'), pos = pos  + 3; -- nxt = ('X', 3)
                        END IF;
                    END IF;
                ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos+2, 1) IN ('I', 'E', 'Y') THEN
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'S'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'S'), pos = pos  + 3; -- nxt = ('S', 3)
                ELSE
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'SK'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'SK'), pos = pos  + 3; -- nxt = ('SK', 3)
                END IF;
            --  french e.g. 'resnais', 'artois'
            ELSEIF pos = last AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-2, 2) IN ('AI', 'OI') THEN
                SET sec = CONCAT(sec, 'S'), pos = pos  + 1; -- nxt = ('', 'S')
            ELSE
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'S'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'S'); -- nxt = ('S',)
                IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) IN ('S', 'Z') THEN
                    SET pos = pos + 2;
                ELSE
                    SET pos = pos + 1;
                END IF;
            END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'T' THEN
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 4) = 'TION' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'X'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'X'), pos = pos  + 3; -- nxt = ('X', 3)
            ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 3) IN ('TIA', 'TCH') THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'X'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'X'), pos = pos  + 3; -- nxt = ('X', 3)
            ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 2) = 'TH' OR SUBSTRING(st, pos, 3) = 'TTH' THEN
                --  special case 'thomas', 'thames' OR germanic
                IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+2, 2) IN ('OM', 'AM') OR SUBSTRING(st, first, 4) IN ('VON ', 'VAN ')
                   OR SUBSTRING(st, first, 3) = 'SCH' THEN
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'T'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'T'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('T', 2)
                ELSE
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, '0'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'T'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('0', 'T', 2)
                END IF;
            ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) IN ('T', 'D') THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'T'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'T'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('T', 2)
            ELSE
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'T'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'T'), pos = pos  + 1; -- nxt = ('T', 1)
            END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'V' THEN
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'V' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'F'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'F'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('F', 2)
            ELSE
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'F'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'F'), pos = pos  + 1; -- nxt = ('F', 1)
            END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'W' THEN
            --  can also be IN middle of word
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 2) = 'WR' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'R'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'R'), pos = pos  + 2; -- nxt = ('R', 2)
            ELSEIF pos = first AND (SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) IN ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y')
                OR SUBSTRING(st, pos, 2) = 'WH') THEN
                --  Wasserman should match Vasserman
                IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) IN ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y') THEN
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'A'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'F'), pos = pos  + 1; -- nxt = ('A', 'F', 1)
                ELSE
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'A'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'A'), pos = pos  + 1; -- nxt = ('A', 1)
                END IF;
            --  Arnow should match Arnoff
            ELSEIF (pos = last AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 1) IN ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y'))
               OR SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 5) IN ('EWSKI', 'EWSKY', 'OWSKI', 'OWSKY')
               OR SUBSTRING(st, first, 3) = 'SCH' THEN
                SET sec = CONCAT(sec, 'F'), pos = pos  + 1; -- nxt = ('', 'F', 1)
            -- END IF;
            --  polish e.g. 'filipowicz'
            ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 4) IN ('WICZ', 'WITZ') THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'TS'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'FX'), pos = pos  + 4; -- nxt = ('TS', 'FX', 4)
            ELSE --  default is to skip it
                SET pos = pos + 1;
            END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'X' THEN
            --  french e.g. breaux
            IF not(pos = last AND (SUBSTRING(st, pos-3, 3) IN ('IAU', 'EAU')
               OR SUBSTRING(st, pos-2, 2) IN ('AU', 'OU'))) THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'KS'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'KS'); -- nxt = ('KS',)
            END IF;
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) IN ('C', 'X') THEN
                SET pos = pos + 2;
            ELSE
                SET pos = pos + 1;
            END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'Z' THEN
            --  chinese pinyin e.g. 'zhao'
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'H' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'J'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'J'), pos = pos  + 1; -- nxt = ('J', 2)
            ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 3) IN ('ZO', 'ZI', 'ZA')
               OR (is_slavo_germanic AND pos > first AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 1) != 'T') THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'S'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'TS'); -- nxt = ('S', 'TS')
            ELSE
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'S'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'S'); -- nxt = ('S',)
            END IF;
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'Z' THEN
                SET pos = pos + 2;
            ELSE
                SET pos = pos + 1;
            END IF;
        ELSE
            SET pos = pos + 1; -- DEFAULT is to move to next char
        END CASE;
    IF pos = prevpos THEN
       SET pos = pos +1;
       SET pri = CONCAT(pri,'<didnt incr>'); -- it might be better to throw an error here if you really must be accurate
    END IF;
    END WHILE;
    IF pri != sec THEN
        SET pri = CONCAT(pri, ';', sec);
  END IF;
    RETURN (pri);
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

First I had errors trying to store the function in MYSQL, stating that "The object's DDL statement contains syntax errors." When I still applied the script it errored out replacing in the output:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `dm` $$
```

with

```
DROP unknown IF EXISTS `unknown_SYNTAX_ERROR`;
```

Removing this line and `DELIMITER $$` and `DELIMITER ;` resolves the error where `SELECT dm("hardcore")` returns `HRTKR`.

Then when trying to implement this function in a trigger through:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `schema_premises`.`table_premises_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `table_premises` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.street_name_dm = dm(NEW.street_name)
END
```

Where `street_name_dm` and `street_name` are both varchar(45) columns of `table_premises`. I get a popup alert that "The object's DDL statement contains syntax errors." with the following message log:

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
USE `schema_premises`;

DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS schema_premises.table_premises_BEFORE_INSERT$$
USE `schema_premises`$$
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `schema_premises`.`table_premises_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `table_premises` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.street_name_dm = dm(NEW.street_name)
END$$
DELIMITER ;

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 4
SQL Statement:
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `schema_premises`.`table_premises_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `table_premises` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.street_name_dm = dm(NEW.street_name)
END
```

Any advise as to why these errors are caused would be greatly appreciated. Warm regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is with the delimiter.

The idea in setting the delimiter to `$$` is that you can create a trigger that contains the regular `;` delimiter inside, but you don't want it to act as delimiter in the process of creating the delimiter. therefor you set the delimiter to `$$` before you define the trigger.

By Doing that, you allow yourself to use `;` inside your create statement, and you don't need `$$` inside like you did. it should look like:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS schema_premises.table_premises_BEFORE_INSERT;
USE `schema_premises`;
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `schema_premises`.`table_premises_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `table_premises` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.street_name_dm = dm(NEW.street_name);
END; $$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Tested successfully. Will provide the bounty tomorrow once SO allows me to. Can't believe that it was just a missing semi-colon that had me racking my brain. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a semicolon at the end of your `SET` statement.

`BEGIN ... END` exists to allow several simple statements to be combined into a single compound statement, but the component simple statements still require the standard statement delimiter.

The `DELIMITER $$` directive is used to allow the compiler to distinguish between the delimiter ending the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement *as a whole* and the one ending any simple statements *within* the trigger definition. This is why you use a semicolon after the `SET` and `$$` after `END`.

Your trigger definition should thus be

```
CREATE
    DEFINER = CURRENT_USER
  TRIGGER `schema_premises`.`table_premises_BEFORE_INSERT`
    BEFORE INSERT ON `table_premises`
    FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    SET NEW.street_name_dm = dm(NEW.street_name); -- add semicolon here
  END$$
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have marked it as useful but I accepted and granted the bounty to the other answer as it was presented first. Thank you regardless.